# See parameters that are overridden from TeamCity template

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Is there a way to see TeamCity configurations that override parameter defined in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. What's worked for me in the past was to search through the project files on the filesystem. If you have many build configs, this will be faster than opening each of them in the GUI.

Search for something like this:

```
<param name="myParamInheritedFromTemplate" value="myOverrideValue" />
```

in `<TeamCity data directory>/config/projects/**/*.xml`. If it's absent in an XML file, that build config just inherits the value. If it's present, it overrides it.

It's hacky but it's quick.

Comment: I accepted this as for the time being, there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21212, please vote. Current workaround are to either search the raw XML files with the settings stored under TeamCity Data Directory on the server as @sferencik suggested, or use REST API to get settings of all the build configurations and search for the parameter there. Let me know if you need help on any of these.